# Browse a page with custom shortcut keys

Tags: web, keyboard-shortcuts, greasemonkey

I want to browse ragecollection.com site using the j and k keys [similar to 9gag.com or google reader] ,  the default is left right arrow which is not ideal when using a laptop ..

grease monkey script for firefox preffered.

Comment: We do not write scripts on demand, from scratch, here.  This is a site to help with ***specific*** programming problems.   You can politely *request* that someone write a script for you at: http://userscripts.org/forums/2 .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use greasemonkey/javascript to simulate the pressing of a key, as this would cause security problems. The approach in javascript would be to intercept a key press event and trigger the required action that would normally be triggered by a different key press.

To get you started, the following greasemonkey script intercepts g and h character presses on any page:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name           keytranslate
// @namespace      ongar.org
// @description    turns g or h keypress into left or right cursor press
// @include        *
// ==/UserScript==


function keycheck(e)
{
if (e.keyCode == 71) // code for g
    {
    // trigger right-cursor event
    }
else if (e.keyCode == 72) // code for h
    {
    // trigger left-cursor event
    }

}

window.addEventListener('keydown', keycheck, true);
```